# Resolving a subnet to a specific domain

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, centos

I am trying to figure out how to resolve a subnet for a specific domain on my CentOS machine. for example Google owns a range of IP addresses and one range in particular is `64.233.160.0 - 64.233.191.255`. Now they also have many more but I will just talk about this range for the question.

What I was originally trying to do was have this range in the /etc/hosts file with the hostname `Google`, but I found out that the /etc/hosts file only takes one IP address per line and not a range of IP addresses or even accepting wildcards.

The reason for the importance on this is we have a product that tracks IP addresses users visit and we want to chart the data on a tree map, but instead of the chart showing `63.233.160.5` we want it to display `Google`.

The only lead I have so far is using the /etc/hosts file but I do not want to single handily type out every single address for Google, then Facebook and so on. Is there another way I could achieve my goal, making life a lot easier for me?

Comment: Use a [Geo Location](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geolocation_software) database/API instead of a DIY solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could easily query [RADb](http://www.radb.net/) for this. Get the ASN for each IP address, and just work with those.

For example:

```
$ whois -h whois.radb.net 63.233.160.5
[Querying whois.radb.net]
[whois.radb.net]
route:              63.232.0.0/14
descr:              Qwest Communications
                    950 17th Street Suite 1900
                    Denver, CO 80202
origin:             AS209
mnt-by:             MAINT-QWEST
changed:            dgassen@qwest.com 20020504
source:             RADB
```

Here we see that this IP is in AS209 (which you can store instead of the IP, or in addition to it, if you wish) and is registered to Qwest Communications, which you can then display.

Comment: I tried `whois -h whois.radb.net 63.233.160.5`and it wouldn't work. After a quick search I seen a lot of articles on `jwois` and inserted a `j` at the start of the command and it is now working perfectly. Thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

If you want to resolve IP addresses to names of networks rather than names of hosts, then you shouldn't be using tools intended to resolve IP addresses to hostnames. In other words, that tool should not be getting the mappings from `/etc/hosts` or by using any of the library calls, which look up the mapping from `/etc/hosts` or through PTR records in DNS.

The tool could be given a separate file with a list of network prefixes and names to display, and optionally fall back to resolving IP address to hostname, if the network is not in the specified file.

Comment: I am not committed to /etc/hosts. Its just we were not sure where to start with this and thought the /etc/hosts file would be a sure lead, but it is obviously not.